# Open Source Java Projects that uses Stripes and hibernate for Beginners?

Tags: java

Im looking for a lightweight open source project that uses Stripes and hibernate for learning purpose. Do you have any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the quality of that project, but how about this: http://code.google.com/p/stripes-hibernate-on-springs/ ?

The description on the project home page says: "A sample project illustrating Stripes and Hibernate combination within the spring framework."

The project has no downloads, but its source is browsable:
http://code.google.com/p/stripes-hibernate-on-springs/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fsrc%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fpkg%2Fdao%253Fstate%253Dclosed